# Can't repair ext4 partition after power outage, e2fsck keeps crashing, can't find out what is wrong?

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive, filesystem, ext4

After power outage, Ubuntu couldn't repair ext4 and throws the same error as below with e2fsck:

So I use the latest SystemRescue LiveCd and try to manually do fsck.

> e2fsck /dev/sda2 :

```
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
Signal (11) SIGSEGV si_code=SEGV_MAPERR fault addr=0x561377ff7000
e2fsck: malloc.c:2539: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Signal (6) SIGABRT si_code=SI_TKILL
```

> tune2fs -l /dev/sda2 :

```
tune2fs 1.46.4 (18-Aug-2021)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          787f0a6f-7d49-409d-80b7-5e4416d5a2bb
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index fast_commit filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean with errors
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              30236672
Block count:              120925696
Reserved block count:     6046284
Free blocks:              16403757
Free inodes:              29241790
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      995
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Mon Apr  2 12:16:18 2018
Last mount time:          Mon Nov  8 10:55:03 2021
Last write time:          Mon Nov  8 14:02:43 2021
Mount count:              2
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Mon Nov  8 10:51:38 2021
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          13 TB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       27918882
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      efb4ad95-8a43-42bc-a03b-0849ccae2ef7
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

> mount /dev/sda2 /mnt :

```
mount: /mnt: can't read superblock on /dev/sda2.
```

> mke2fs -n /dev/sda2 :

```
mke2fs 1.46.4 (18-Aug-2021)
/dev/sda2 contains a ext4 file system
    last mounted on / on Mon Nov  8 10:55:03 2021
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
Creating filesystem with 120925696 4k blocks and 30236672 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 331dfa9a-1bae-44bf-b4a2-4c75d7a8aab2
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000
```

> e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda2 :

```
e2fsck 1.46.4 (18-Aug-2021)
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Recovery flag not set in backup superblock, so running journal anyway.
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
Signal (11) SIGSEGV si_code=SEGV_MAPERR fault addr=0x55657e320000
e2fsck(+0x35133)[0x55657d929133]
/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x13870)[0x7fb669365870]
e2fsck(+0x27c10)[0x55657d91bc10]
e2fsck(+0x28480)[0x55657d91c480]
e2fsck(+0x309c4)[0x55657d9249c4]
e2fsck(jbd2_journal_recover+0xd7)[0x55657d9251a7]
e2fsck(e2fsck_run_ext3_journal+0x2d1)[0x55657d91e871]
e2fsck(main+0x1d75)[0x55657d903de5]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xd5)[0x7fb6691adb25]
e2fsck(_start+0x2e)[0x55657d90591e]
```

> e2fsck -b 98304 /dev/sda2:

```
e2fsck 1.46.4 (18-Aug-2021)
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Recovery flag not set in backup superblock, so running journal anyway.
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
Signal (11) SIGSEGV si_code=SEGV_MAPERR fault addr=0x563839a50000
e2fsck(+0x35133)[0x563838e06133]
/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x13870)[0x7f671f521870]
e2fsck(+0x27c10)[0x563838df8c10]
e2fsck(+0x28480)[0x563838df9480]
e2fsck(+0x309c4)[0x563838e019c4]
e2fsck(jbd2_journal_recover+0xd7)[0x563838e021a7]
e2fsck(e2fsck_run_ext3_journal+0x2d1)[0x563838dfb871]
e2fsck(main+0x1d75)[0x563838de0de5]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xd5)[0x7f671f369b25]
e2fsck(_start+0x2e)[0x563838de291e]
```

> e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sda2 :

```
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
Signal (11) SIGSEGV si_code=SEGV_MAPERR fault addr=0x555ae23f5000
e2fsck(+0x35133)[0x555ae03cd133]
/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x13870)[0x7efe927b8870]
e2fsck(+0x27c10)[0x555ae03bfc10]
e2fsck(+0x28480)[0x555ae03c0480]
e2fsck(+0x309c4)[0x555ae03c89c4]
e2fsck(jbd2_journal_recover+0xd7)[0x555ae03c91a7]
e2fsck(e2fsck_run_ext3_journal+0x2d1)[0x555ae03c2871]
e2fsck(main+0x1d75)[0x555ae03a7de5]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xd5)[0x7efe92600b25]
e2fsck(_start+0x2e)[0x555ae03a991e]
```

> smartctl -H /dev/sda2:

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.10.70-1-lts] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

Comment: Are there important unique data on the drive, that you must recover? Or would you be happy, if you can blank the partition table, create a new one, create partitions and file systems and restore data from backup?

Comment: Yes, I have some important data. But I'm just interested, what is wrong and why fsck/e2fsck keeps crashing.

Comment: I can't tell what's wrong, but there are tools from https://cgsecurity.org, that might work, when fsck/e2fsck keeps crashing. If very important data, clone the whole drive to another drive of at least the same size and do recovery work on the cloned copy. Try first `testdisk`, and if it does not work, `photorec`, that can recover data without any file system, as long as the file data is still there. But it is a lot of work, and file names and directory strucure are lost..

Comment: Files seems "intact" on partition, using testdisk, so maybe I try to copy from there.

Comment: Let us know the result. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an issue on github, and some nice guy (*harshadjs*) helped me to fix this issue, writing patch for the app. It looks like, it was something wrong with *e2fsprogs* and *fast_commit* feature in ext4.
[One can track it here.](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/issues/85)

Bottom line is, don't mess with filesystem features, when your power supply is unstable and you don't know how to fix it on your own.